# successfully deployed flask app but getting a 404 when accessing the page

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was able to deploy a sample flask app to AWS using the instructions from this document
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html

the status from "eb status" is Green

Retrieving status of environment "helloflask-env" shows

=================================================================

URL : helloflask-env-m3mncmbmpv.elasticbeanstalk.com

Status  : Ready

Health  : Green

Environment Name:   helloflask-env

Environment ID:  e-mdp3jwtq9p

Solution Stack:  64bit Amazon Linux running Python

Version Label:   git-05103eab3255781f58fdbaf1df8078aa4b008d4b-1369170804114

Date Created:    2013-05-21 10:45:25

Date Updated:    2013-05-21 14:14:33

=================================================================

However, when trying to access the url helloflask-env-m3mncmbmpv.elasticbeanstalk.com, I get a 404 error with the following message:

*Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Amazon) Server at helloflask-env-m3mncmbmpv.elasticbeanstalk.com Port 80*

Has anyone seen something similar to this? 
thanks!

Comment: anybody knows the answer to this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I have the same exact problem.

Comment: I learned a lot by looking at the Elastic Beanstalk logs. May help you as well.

Comment: thanks. did you figure out the solution for your case?

Comment: I had a couple of issues.  I wasn't using application.py as the name of my app and I wasn't using this form "application = Flask(__name__)".  For some reason EB requires this rather than "app = Flask(__name__)".

Comment: It might be helpful if you post the exact code you used and uploaded. Maybe you made a simple syntax mistake there or something along those lines.

Comment: thanks for all the replies, the EB logs is extremely useful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured out the error in my case. It's due to a WSGIPath error.

The error occurred because I have the application.py in the app/ folder.  But because I ran the git .init command in its parent folder, EB errors out because it cannot find application.py file.

In short, the solution is to run "eb init" in the same location where you have your application.py file!

Comment: Please, mark your answer as correct if it really solves your problem.

Answer (score 6):

I also had a same issue.
I'm using flask 0.10 and now it works fine.

from example

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")     
def hello():         
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":         
    app.run()
```

to

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)  # Change assignment here

@application.route("/")        # Change your route statements
def hello():         
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":         
    application.run()          # Change all other references to 'app'
```

this [link](http://blog.uptill3.com/2012/08/25/python-on-elastic-beanstalk.html) will help you.